# Would containing NSData in a different Core Data entity make retrieval of the original entity faster?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

So here's my example. I have an entity called Photo. It has the attributes of 'width' and 'height', for easy retrieval, and a NSDate of when it was taken. It also has an NSData of the photo itself. If i moved this NSData to an attribute with a one-to-one relationship to Photo, would it increase saving speed if I changed another attribute in Photo, or fetching speed if i fetched another attribute in Photo?

Comment: As always, questions about performance should be answered with hard data from instruments.  People are terrible at guessing where the real performance bottlenecks are in an application... especially strangers on the internet with zero knowledge of your code.  Then, if you don't understand the data, ask the performance questions.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest making it a external data reference. 
 There is an example of this exact thing in one of the WWDC talks https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/  where they go through the speed of the different types of schema and their fetch times. The talk is called Core Data Best Practices and is a long demo around the 35 min. mark where they talk about external data refs. The whole talk is very very good but that is the relevant bit.

Your idea is correct, they create a 1-1  separate entity with a external data ref. and it speeds things up a lot.

Here is a link to the slides:
http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_session_pdfs/session_214__core_data_best_practices.pdf